# onkeypress repeat always returns false in some browsers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer

If I run "document.onkeypress = function(e) {console.log(e.repeat);}" in the console on Chrome/IE11, then hold down a key in the page, the console outputs false continuously.

On Firefox, I get one false and then a bunch of true.

If I replace onkeypress with onkeydown in Chrome, I get one false and then a bunch of true. IE11 still returns only false.

Is it expected behavior to always receive false for e.repeat in onkeypress, or is it a Chrome/IE11 issue?

Comment: Check support https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/repeat

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks, MDN says IE doesn't support it. MDN says that Chrome supports repeat, and it does for onkeydown, but I'm not sure why onkeypress behavior is different.